# Question about javascript setFocus in PDF fillable forms - does setFocus affect tab order?

Tags: javascript, pdf, setfocus

Thanks for any input! I'm creating a PDF fillable form that will be completed offline (no web browser, no HTML). I have required fields, and code to ensure that these fields are filled. Each required field has an On Blur JavaScript, and there is a final "Check Form" button the user must press before being prompted to save the form.

Originally, I tried using setFocus() on the field with missing data. But there is strange behavior...if I tab out of the field and get the error message, the focus returns to the field. That's fine - but once I fill in the data, the tab scrolls to a field near the bottom of the form (a set of radio buttons , actually). It scrolls to the same set of radio buttons, no matter which other field I run the above scenario on. I checked the tab order, it is as expected (as I set it), so I do not understand why the tab would go many fields down.

In the spirit of "magical" programming, I tried the setFocus statement before and after the alert, with no different behavior.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is there something I'm not understanding about the javascript/field interaction? For now, I'm removing the setFocus statements in the field, but leaving it in the Check Form button.

I'm fairly new to JavaScript, learning new stuff daily, and mostly just curious as to what is going on. I have looked through the postings, most of which concern browser behavior, but seen anything similar.

A typical field check is:

```
var f0 = this.getField("City")
if (f0.value.length == 0) {
    f0.setFocus();
    app.alert("Required - please enter city");
```

}

Comment: In answer to your question... the tab order is the tab order. Using a JavaScript to set the focus into a field will not change the tab order and tabbing out of the field will set the focus to the next field in the tab order **from that field**. However, you should consider using the field validate script and setting the event.rc property to validate fields instead of allowing the value to be committed and then using setFocus.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Hmmm...I did try using validation, but it appeared to get stuck in a never-ending loop or not execute - but that is likely my level of still learning. I will continue to read & dig into -